# Colorbox ajax loading of outside HTML content works perfect on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, ajax

I am trying to render content generated by a php file in [jQuery Colorbox][1] through AJAX in my WordPress site. The PHP resides on the same server in the same domain. It works perfect when I run it on localhost but it's not working on the server.

Here is the link to my site - http://shabdcreatives.com/portfolio

The links themselves are not invalid, for example the following link works fine on its own:

http://shabdcreatives.com/wp-content/plugins/catgrid/includes/CatGridPost.php?ID=33

I just won't open inside the colorbox.

Also the php file I am trying to load is just a fragment and DOES NOT CONTAIN any  or  tags.

I tried the colorbox support group but no replies from them yet

This is the code in the CatGridPost.php file that i am calling in the colorbox.. i tried calling a plain text file too... it returned no error.. but the colorbox did not show its contents either

```
require_once("../../../../wp-blog-header.php");
$thepost = get_post($_GET["ID"]);
$thecontent = $thepost->post_content;
$thetitle = $thepost->post_title;
$thelink = get_permalink($_GET["ID"]);
?>
<div id="cg-post-container">
<div id="cg-post-title">
<a href="<?php echo $thelink; ?>"><?php echo $thetitle; ?></a>
</div>
<div id="cg-post-content">  
    <?php echo $thecontent; ?>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* load wp-blog-header.php yourself.

Use `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` instead, as described here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: im sorry i dont understand wot i have to do.. plus it is working just fine on localhost... please can u elaborate more.. i dint get it through that link

Comment: Since you're loading WP manually, it's sending a 404 header, while also outputting the correct content. Let me know what exactly is unclear in the tutorial I linked to.

Comment: i dint get what exactly i hv to modify.. just the php.. or the colorbox js? .. im sorry . im a newbie.. :S

Comment: I would suggest getting the code on the codex working, then figure out how to modify it for your case.

Comment: yea i got it to work... thanx.. i shouldnt have loaded wp-blog-header.php